# How to repeat the same command in creating the openstack backup?

Tags: ansible, backup, openstack, cinder, openstack-cinder

I took volumes '`in-use`' of OpenStack instance and filtered those volume ids into a file from which it has to make a backup

```
shell: openstack volume list | grep 'in-use' | awk '{print $2}' > /home/volumeid   

shell: openstack volume backup create {{ item }}
with_items:
- /home/volumeid
```

error shows like

```
**failed: [controller2] (item=volumeid) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "openstack volume backup create volumeid", "delta": "0:00:03.682611", "end": "2022-09-26 12:01:59.961613", "item": "volumeid", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-09-26 12:01:56.279002", "stderr": "No volume with a name or ID of 'volumeid' exists.", "stderr_lines": ["No volume with a name or ID of 'volumeid' exists."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
failed: [controller1] (item=volumeid) => {"ansible_loop_var": "item", "changed": true, "cmd": "openstack volume backup create volumeid", "delta": "0:00:04.020051", "end": "2022-09-26 12:02:00.280130", "item": "volumeid", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2022-09-26 12:01:56.260079", "stderr": "No volume with a name or ID of 'volumeid' exists.", "stderr_lines": ["No volume with a name or ID of 'volumeid' exists."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}**
```

Can someone say how to create the volume backup from that file (which has volume ids) in the ansible playbook?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you are supplying only one element to the `with_items,` that is, `/home/volumeid`, meaning your loop will iterate only once for the file name and not its contents.

You need to use the `file` lookup if you are on localhost or the `slurp` module on the remote host. Example:

**For the `localhost`:**

```
- name: Show the volume id from the file
  debug:
    msg: "{{ item }}"
  loop: "{{ lookup('file', '/home/volumeid').splitlines() }}"
```

**For the remote host:**

```
  - name: Alternate if the file is on remote host
    ansible.builtin.slurp:
      src: /home/volumeid
    register: vol_data

  - name: Show the volume id from the file
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item }}"
    loop: "{{ (vol_data['content'] | b64decode).splitlines() }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just one line shell command:

```
openstack volume list --status in-use -c ID -f value | xargs -n1 openstack volume backup create
```

One advice, don't use the hardcode command like this `grep 'in-use'` or `awk '{print $2}'`, `openstack` has it's **optional arguments** and **output formatters**, check it by `openstack command [sub command] -h`.

Comment: Thank you .Let me try this command in my ansible playbook